# custom robotic arm

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone

i have recently completed navigation on my custom robot base, and planning to make own robotic arm controlled by moveit.

for that , i searched-on wiki pages and ros-industrial tutorials.

my progress on this is as follows
1.have  my robots urdf file
2.completed moveit setup assistant
3.demo.launch runs completely well.
4.controller.yaml
5.moveit_planning_execution.launch

now i'm struct!!where to go now!!
i think next phase is writting custom hardware node listen to the trajectory.
bt  i'm not sure

can anyone guide me ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223149/custom-robotic-arm/) by [denim_patel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24047/denim_patel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Had the same problem and after a lot of websearches I ended up writing an [ActionLib Server](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib) for the [FollowJointTrajectoryAction](http://docs.ros.org/electric/api/control_msgs/html/action/FollowJointTrajectory.html)

- You get the list of goals for each link in [trajectory/points](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/trajectory_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectory.html)
- You should publish the feedback for each goal while also watching preempt_requested.
- Moveit expects you to return FollowJointTrajectoryResult.SUCCESSFUL in [FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult](http://docs.ros.org/electric/api/control_msgs/html/msg/FollowJointTrajectoryAction.html) if all went well.

In case it helps I uploaded my implementation (python) to [github](https://github.com/nxdefiant/arm_ros_conn/blob/master/scripts/arm_ros.py), no guarantees given.

The new angle is send to hardware with the to_angle() call (not in this repos). The interface is

```
def to_angle(axis, speed=255, angle=0)
```

where axis is the axis number (0..5), speed the motor pwm speed and angle in rad.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [denim_patel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24047/denim_patel/) on 2015-12-28**:
thanks for the precious help!!!

**Comment by [denim_patel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24047/denim_patel/) on 2015-12-30**:
thank you for sharing!!!
i worked on your implementation but there is a problem with one module "arm".
no module is added in your pkg present on git-hub named "arm".
can you please upload it?
thank you

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2015-12-31**:
I could share it, but this is the call to the hardware which you most certainly do not need. It basically sends an i2c call to the different motor/servo controllers. I have updated my answer with the detail.

**Comment by [denim_patel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24047/denim_patel/) on 2015-12-31**:
thank you for all the help!!!

**Comment by [denim_patel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24047/denim_patel/) on 2016-01-01**:
using your guidance and your code, I completed my node of action server client.
Right now i am working on changing the settings from fake_trajectory_execution to arm_trajectory_execution.

does am i doing right?
it will be great if you suggest me the process of the same in fewer lines.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-01-01**:
Sorry not sure if I fully understood you. There should be no need to change any of the launch files created by moveit. For real hardware I just use move_group.launch instead of demo.launch.

Also this might better go into a new question.

**Comment by [Robo_Panda](https://answers.ros.org/users/36827/robo_panda/) on 2018-08-15**:
Hey @humpelstilzchen, could you share the link of your github implementation again, the current one is not working. It would be a great help.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2018-08-15**:
Try [arm_ros.py on private repo](https://defiant.homedns.org/gitweb/?p=arm_ros_conn.git;a=blob;f=scripts/arm_ros.py;h=4d079ae82cd3c264ecbb02069e2efce7937a03a5;hb=HEAD). But an implementation based on ros control might be prefered.